# Showing properties of equivalence relation

Tags: real-analysis, equivalence-relations

I just started my abstract algebra class and I am struggling with the concept of equivalence relations. I know that in order to prove equivalence relations, I have to prove the reflexive, symmetric, and transitive properties. However, I don't know how to go about starting the actual proof or solution. I have these examples and any help would be appreciated.

> a) Given sets $A$ and $B$, explain why $A~B$ is equivalent to asserting $B \sim A$
>
> b) For three sets $A, B$, and $C$, show that $A \sim B$ and $B \sim C → A \sim C$

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Is there a reason you assume $A$, $B$, etc. to be sets?  If you write $A\sim B$, do you mean $a\sim b$ for $a\in A,b\in B$ or that the equivalence relation is defined over some class of sets?

Comment: In my textbook, I am given that A and B are sets, so I assumed that they would be sets. When I write A~B, I mean that the equivalence relation is defined over some class of sets. Although, I have to show that the equivalence is defined over sets A, B, and C in part b.